# How to form valid XSD which helps in serialsing into c# classes

Tags: c#, serialization, xsd

I have developed XSD, which define standards and it helps in communicating two application together. Application A and B.

Application A read xml data from B correctly. But when it try to convert/serialized the same data to xml it serialized wrongly.

**XML examples are: (wants like as)**

```
   <Field>
      <FieldId>1</FieldId>
       <FieldType>  
          <FieldTypeString>John</FieldTypeString>
       </FieldType>
    <\Field>
or
    <Field>
      <FieldId>2</FieldId>
      <FieldType>  
        <FieldTypeInteger>30</FieldTypeString>
      </FieldType>
    <\Field>

 or   
    <Field>
      <FieldId>3</FieldId>
      <FieldType>  
        <FieldTypeDate>19/06/2019</FieldTypeString>
      </FieldType>
    <\Field>
```

**Equivalent XSD is:**
[image]

**Equivalent C# class is:**

```
public partial class FieldGroupFieldColumnFieldFieldType
{

    private object itemField;

    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FieldTypeCheckedUnChecked", typeof(bool))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FieldTypeDate", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType = "date")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FieldTypeFloat", typeof(decimal))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FieldTypeInteger", typeof(string), DataType = "integer")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FieldTypeString", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FieldTypeTime", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType = "time")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FieldTypeYESNO", typeof(bool))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Application A parse perfectly the xml from B. But when it self generate the XML its looks like.

```
<Field>
      <FieldId>1</FieldId>
       <FieldType>  
          <Item>John</FieldTypeString>
          <ItemElementName>2</ItemElementName>
       </FieldType>
<\Field>
```

I think the XSD/class property needs to be modified!

Any suggestion about it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"it get wrong"_ - probably isn't a useful description of the problem.  Do you have the code that actually does the serialization to XML?  Also, your XML is arguably wrong.  Where is the `<?xml ...` header?  Where is the `xmlns` that refers to your schema?  You might want to check out _Stylus Studio_.  It's awesome for this sort of thing

Comment: I have attached parts of xml and xsd. not complete at all.

Comment: Ah I see what you are referring to, would have been useful if your said `ItemElementName` is appearing when it shouldn't.  What is causing `ItemElementName` to appear in the C# in the first place?    Fix that and I suspect the generated XML that `B` is trying to read will succeed

Comment: @MickyD. I agree with you. It should be generate like. <Field>
      <FieldId>1</FieldId>
       <FieldType>  
          <FieldTypeString>John</FieldTypeString>
       </FieldType>
    <\Field>~

Comment: How did you create the C# class?

Comment: by using xsd.exe command.

Answer (score 1):

Use xsd.exe to translate xsd to C#, dont go by hand.

Also, for readability, you should isolate complex types. When an element contains a complex type, declare the complex type as a named type under the XSD root, not inside the element.

When declaring the element then, reference the complex type with `xs:type="tns:complextypename"`

EDIT: The same applies to simple types.

Comment: xsd.exe is only a partial solution. Last time I looked it ignored value and (I think) size constraints. The OP is using the latter to some extent. MS's reason for not doing it properly is rather spurious, amounting to "we can't be bothered to make our code generator generate a bit more code". I have found very few tools that do this properly - the XBinder from Objective Systems does, but costs money (no I don't work for them!). It does have the added advantage of generating code for many more languages than C#, so it's good in heterogenous systems.